# pandas: assign random numbers in given range to equal column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I am working with a large dataset, and one of the columns has very long integers, like below:

```
       Column_1        Column_2
  1     A              12345123451
  2     B              12345123451
  3     C              12345123451
  4     D              23456789234
  5     E              23456789234
  6     F              34567893456
```

What is important here is not the actual number in Column_2, but when those numbers are the same while Column_1 is different. I would like to reassign the values of Column_2 randomly from a range of smaller numbers, say (1, 999).

```
       Column_1        Column_2
  1     A              120
  2     B              120
  3     C              120
  4     D              54
  5     E              54
  6     F              567
```

My issue is figuring a way to describe in a lambda function that each equal value in Column_2 needs the same random number.

Comment: It looks to me like OP only cares about `'Column_2'`.  If `'Column_1'` is the same, I suspect it has no bearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array of random numbers between 1 and 999 using `np.random.choice`, making sure to say `replace=False` so you don't get any duplicates, and then map `Column_2` to a dictionary mapping of `Column_2` unique values with your array of random numbers:

```
import numpy as np 

nums = np.random.choice(range(1,999), size = df['Column_2'].nunique(), replace=False)

# If you prefer to use the random package rather than numpy, uncomment the following:
# import random
# nums = random.sample(range(1,999), df['Column_2'].nunique())

df['Column_2'] = df['Column_2'].map(dict(zip(df['Column_2'].unique(), nums)))

>>> df
  Column_1  Column_2
1        A       274
2        B       274
3        C       274
4        D       842
5        E       842
6        F       860
```

**Explanation:**

Your array of numbers looks like:

```
>>> nums
array([274, 842, 860])
```

And your mapping dictionary looks like:

```
>>> dict(zip(df['Column_2'].unique(), nums))
{12345123451: 274, 23456789234: 842, 34567893456: 860}
```

So when you map, you are saying to replace `12345123451` with `274`, `23456789234` with `842`, and so on...

Comment: Let me ask another question: these random numbers cannot be same right? If you dinamically generate random numbers, you might get same numbers for different groups

Comment: That's what the `replace=False` is for. When you use `np.random.choice` with that argument, it will make sure there are no duplicates. Same with `random.sample` (by default)

Comment: Awesome :} didnt see `replace=False` +1

Answer (score 3):

Took a cue from sacul on `replace=False` (updated answer)

### Using `pandas.factorize` and `numpy.random`

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.Column_2)
choices = np.arange(max(999, r.size))
c = np.random.choice(choices, r.shape, False)

df.assign(Column_2=c[i])

  Column_1  Column_2
1        A       812
2        B       812
3        C       812
4        D       751
5        E       751
6        F       574
```

Comment: Since it seems OP actually doesn't care about the values of `Column_2` in the end, I guess they could choose to just actually use `df['Column_2'] = pd.factorize(df.Column_2)[0]`, and just have it end up as `[0,0,0,1,1,2]`... Not random, but if the goal were just to have distinct categories for each, it would work. In any case, I like your method!

Comment: That is true.  We'll see if OP really wanted random `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`